# Python iterate over each individual list that is stored in a variable and make it as single list

Tags: python

I have lists stored in the variable
`x = ['eventVersion', '1.08'] ['userIdentity', {'type': 'IAMUser', 'principalId': '', 'accountId': '', 'accessKeyId': '', 'userName': 'test'}] ['eventTime', '2021-09-22T13:49:49Z'] ['eventSource', 'signin.amazonaws.com']`

I am trying to convert this to a single list, I tried to loop through a list but is only providing 'eventVersion', '1.08'. How can I loop through the entire each sub-list and get all the information?

Appreciate your help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you provide a valid python data sample? Code you added contains syntax errors.

Comment: this is the code, i tried `for i in x:
    for j in i:
        print(j)`

Comment: That's a non-starter because your declaration of **x** is broken. Once you've fixed that, let us know what output you're trying to get

Comment: this is the same `x = ['eventVersion', '1.08']
['userIdentity', {'type': 'IAMUser', 'principalId': '', 'accountId': '', 'accessKeyId': '', 'userName': 'test'}]
['eventTime', '2021-09-22T13:49:49Z']
['eventSource', 'signin.amazonaws.com']
['eventName', 'ConsoleLogin']
['awsRegion', 'us-east-1']
['sourceIPAddress', '.']
['userAgent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36']
['errorMessage', 'Failed authentication']
['requestParameters', None]`

Comment: That is not valid Python

Comment: @DarkKnight you mean I should not declare x = ? in this format?, because I am getting this information from this output `outelem = [item for item in x
                   if eventstat == "Failure" and uname]` , basically I am trying to total count "Failure" in list

Comment: Your attempt at initialising **x** in the way you have shown cannot be processed by the Python interpreter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237460/discussion-between-suppala-and-darkknight).

Comment: Provide expected output.

Comment: @DankDizaster like this `["eventVersion":"1.08","userIdentity":{"type":"IAMUser","principalId":"","arn":"","accountId":"","userName":""},"eventTime":"2021-09-24T13:48:09Z","eventSource":"signin.amazonaws.com","eventName":"ConsoleLogin","awsRegion":"us-east-1","sourceIPAddress":"71.184.114.252","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36 Edg/93.0.961.52","requestParameters":null,"responseElements":{"ConsoleLogin":"Success"},"additionalEventData"}']`

Comment: That's isn't a valid Python data structure either

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this as the input and the expected output provided in the comments, a dictionary is needed to get it to the key:value pair format, cant use a list.

```
x = [
        ['eventVersion', '1.08'], 
        [{'userIdentity': 
          {
                'type': 'IAMUser', 
                'principalId': '', 
                'accountId': '', 
                'accessKeyId': '', 
                'userName': 'test'
           }
         }], 
        ['eventTime', '2021-09-22T13:49:49Z'], 
        ['eventSource', 'signin.amazonaws.com'], 
        ['eventName', 'ConsoleLogin'], 
        ['awsRegion', 'us-east-1'], 
        ['sourceIPAddress', '.'], 
        ['userAgent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36'], 
        ['errorMessage', 'Failed authentication'], 
        ['requestParameters', None],
        [{"responseElements":{"ConsoleLogin":"Success"}}],
        [{"additionalEventData" : ""}]
]

converted = {}

for item in x:
    if isinstance(item[0], dict):
        converted.update(item[0])
        continue
    converted[item[0]] = item[1]

for k,v in converted.items():
    print(k," : ",v)
```

Gives output

```
eventVersion  :  1.08
userIdentity  :  {'type': 'IAMUser', 'principalId': '', 'accountId': '', 'accessKeyId': '', 'userName': 'test'}
eventTime  :  2021-09-22T13:49:49Z
eventSource  :  signin.amazonaws.com
eventName  :  ConsoleLogin
awsRegion  :  us-east-1
sourceIPAddress  :  .
userAgent  :  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36
errorMessage  :  Failed authentication
requestParameters  :  None
responseElements  :  {'ConsoleLogin': 'Success'}
additionalEventData  :
```